# Draggable box in jquery-ui sliders not rendering

Tags: jquery-ui, datetimepicker, sliders

I am using Trent Richardson's [timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) and I am having an issue with the jquery-ui sliders that are used in his widget.  The draggable boxes in the sliders are not rendering fully.  I am left with what looks like the border of what would have been the boxes on the far left side of the slider and it does not move when I click on it.

I have tried using this tool with the full version of jquery and jquery-ui packages so I know that I am not missing a package and I have not found anyone else with a similar problem.  Everything else works just fine in the timepicker so I believe that this is a problem specific to the slider.  My javascript is identical to the first example shown in the link above.

Has anyone experience a similar problem when working with sliders?

**UPDATE**

Found the issue.  It turns out I did not have sliders selected when I downloaded the css files for my datepicker.  I had since then downloaded the necessary slider functions but forgot to redownload the css...

DOH!

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's it, the solutin is to add the slider css to your project. The file can be found here :
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui/source/browse/trunk/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css